SFTTrainer doesn't show added column
I am trying to add info about learning rate to my trainer log:
from trl import SFTTrainer
from transformers import TrainingArguments
from typing import Dict

class MyTrainer(SFTTrainer):
    def log(self, logs: Dict[str, float]) -> None:
        logs["learning_rate"] = self._get_learning_rate()
        super().log(logs)

trainer = MyTrainer(
    model = model,
    tokenizer = tokenizer,
    train_dataset = train_dataset,
    dataset_text_field = "text",
    max_seq_length = max_seq_length,
    dataset_num_proc = 2,
    packing = False,
    args = TrainingArguments(
        per_device_train_batch_size = 2,
        gradient_accumulation_steps = 4,
        warmup_steps = 5,
        max_steps = 64,
        learning_rate = 2e-4,
        fp16 = not torch.cuda.is_bf16_supported(),
        bf16 = torch.cuda.is_bf16_supported(),
        logging_steps = 1,
        optim = "adamw_8bit",
        weight_decay = 0.01,
        lr_scheduler_type = "linear",
        seed = 3407,
        output_dir = "outputs",
    ),
)

But it still shows the loss only:
Step    Training Loss
1   2.191700
2   2.246300
3   2.154900
4   1.919800
5   1.667400

